# Dijkstra algorithm, loop, C

Tags: c, pointers, codeblocks

In my project, which is looking for shortest path, I cannot leave the loop. Does anyone have an idea why not?

The first piece of code is part of function loading start and end city from a `.txt` file, and the second piece is a subfunction that returns pointer to next city with short way:

```
if(wsk_miasta_p != 0||wsk_miasta_p != 0)
{
    wsk_miasta_p->odleglosc = 0;
    while(szukaj_najmniejszej_odl(&phead) != 0)
    {
        miasta *wsk_najmniejsza_odleglosc = szukaj_najmniejszej_odl(&phead);
        wsk_najmniejsza_odleglosc->odwiedzone = true;
        sasiedzi *wsk_s_tmp = wsk_najmniejsza_odleglosc ->phead_s;
        while(wsk_s_tmp)
        {
            if(wsk_s_tmp->sasiad->odleglosc > (wsk_najmniejsza_odleglosc->odleglosc + wsk_s_tmp->odl_do_sasiada))
            {
                wsk_s_tmp->sasiad->odleglosc = wsk_najmniejsza_odleglosc->odleglosc + wsk_s_tmp->odl_do_sasiada;
                wsk_s_tmp->sasiad->pprev = wsk_najmniejsza_odleglosc;
            }
            wsk_s_tmp = wsk_s_tmp->pnext_s;
        }
    }
}

miasta* szukaj_najmniejszej_odl(miasta **phead){
    int min_tmp = 214748646;
    miasta *wsk_najmniejsza_odl = *phead;
    miasta *wsk_tmp = *phead;
    while(wsk_tmp)
    {
        if(min_tmp > wsk_tmp->odleglosc && wsk_tmp->odwiedzone == false)
        {
            min_tmp = wsk_tmp->odleglosc;
            wsk_najmniejsza_odl = wsk_tmp;
        }
        wsk_tmp= wsk_tmp->pnext;
    }
    if(wsk_najmniejsza_odl->odleglosc == 214748646){
        return 0; // zwraca zero gdy po przeszukaniu najmniejsza odleglosc to nieskonczonosc
    }
    else
        return wsk_najmniejsza_odl;
}
```

DATA STRUCTURES

```
typedef struct miasta miasta;  cities
struct miasta {
char nazwa_miasta[50];           //city's name
int odleglosc;                  //distance of path
miasta *pprev;                 //previous city in path
miasta *pnext;                // next city in path
bool odwiedzone;             // check if town was visted
struct sasiedzi *phead_s;   //address of the list of neighbors of a given city
};

typedef struct sasiedzi sasiedzi;  neighbors 
struct sasiedzi {
int odl_do_sasiada;         //distance beetwen city and neigbhor
miasta *sasiad; ;          //adress of neighboring city
sasiedzi *pnext_s;        //next city on neighbor's list
};
```

Comment: Rename the variables to English. I have no idea what anything means.

Comment: I think you need to show the data structures and variable declarations.  It's necessary to make head or tail of the code when you don't speak Polish ("zwraca zero gdy po przeszukaniu najmniejsza odleglosc to nieskonczonosc" translates from Polish to "Returns zero when, after searching, the smallest distance is infinity" according to Google).  The use of 214748646 instead of `INT_MAX-1` is a minor problem in the code.  I'd really like to see an MCVE ([MCVE]) for the code — with a description of the input and so on.  You should be using a debugger or print statements to track what's happening.

Comment: i've added data structures